# How and when does a service get automatically restarted in Android

Tags: android

According to the docs (ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle), android will automatically restart a service that is killed due to low memory.

To quote:

> Note this means that most of the time your service is running, it may be killed by the system if it is under heavy memory pressure. If this happens, the system will later try to restart the service.

My questions are:
(1) How does the system decide which services to restart?
(2) When is "later"?

Comment: AFAIK, neither is documented, and so you probably should not make any assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Processes on the Android work in a hierarchical structure, so whatever services are on the top of the list get restarted first. This also applies to active processes, so if you have a process in the foreground that you are running, that foreground service is at the top of the list and will be removed first. It's pretty much a stack. I think that processes under higher memory pressure are moved up in priority, but who knows, you would have to look at the belly of the beast to see what's actually happening.